# Update table column with the columns default value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection dataConnection = new SqlConnection();
dataConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand dataCommand = new SqlCommand();
dataCommand.Connection = dataConnection;

long MachineGroupID = Convert.ToInt64(Request.QueryString["node"]);
dataCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE [MachineGroups] SET [MachineGroupName]=@MachineGroupName,[MachineGroupDesc]=@MachineGroupDesc WHERE [MachineGroupID]= @MachineGroupID";

//add our parameters to our command object  
dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MachineGroupName", MachineGroupName);
dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MachineGroupDesc", MachineGroupDesc);

dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MachineGroupID", MachineGroupID);

dataConnection.Open();
dataCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
dataConnection.Close();
```

here the MachineGroups table has a column "tval" which was first inserted with user value and then on updating it should put the default value set by the SQl value when created...

for example

```
[tval] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((2147483647))
```

this is how the column was created, and now i want to put the value 2147483647 on updating.

also i cannot fix the value as "2147483647" coz that might change..

any suggestions??

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried to use the `DEFAULT` keyword?  For example:

```
UPDATE [MachineGroups] SET [tval] = DEFAULT 
WHERE [MachineGroupID] = @MachineGroupID
```

This is supported by the SQL standard, and the [syntax docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523%28SQL.90%29.aspx) for `UPDATE` indicate that Microsoft SQL Server supports this usage of the `DEFAULT` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

If your SQL server is MS SQL then you might try:

```
UPDATE [MachineGroups] 
SET [MachineGroupName]=@MachineGroupName
,[MachineGroupDesc]=@MachineGroupDesc 
,[tval]=DEFAULT
WHERE [MachineGroupID]= @MachineGroupID
```

Other SQL servers will probably have a similar syntax.

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to always use the default value for [tval] whenever you update a row, just include that in your update statement:

```
dataCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE [MachineGroups] SET [MachineGroupName]=@MachineGroupName,[MachineGroupDesc]=@MachineGroupDesc, [tval] = default** WHERE [MachineGroupID]= @MachineGroupID";
```

That will always use your defined default whenever you call your update.

Answer (score 0):

Use ALTER TABLE and ON UPDATE SET DEFAULT

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174123.aspx